# General equation of a point on a line, coordinate geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm going through coordinate geometry chapter and I cannot understand where the formula below comes from.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be distinct point. The line from $O$ to $X-Y$ is parallel to line from $Y$ to $X$. A point on the line from $Y$ to $X$ is of the form:

$$P = Y + a(X - Y) = aX + (1 - a)Y,$$

where $a$ is a real number.

Comment: Is it clear to you that $P= aX + (1-a)Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are points and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, is a straight line? When that's clear, you can check what happens when $a=0$ and when $a=1$, and you'll see that it's indeed a line that passes through $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: For $a=0$, $P=Y$ and for $a=1$, $P=X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following diagram should help you visualize the relationship of all the points.

[image]

As you can see in the diagram, the line from $O$ to $X-Y$ is parallel to the line from $Y$ to $X$ and the point $P$ on this line is just $P=Y+Z$, with $Z= a(X-Y)$.